# Is BOXI 3.1 compatible with 12c database

Tags: oracle

We are upgrading database from 10g to 12c, but are concerned whether BOXI 3.1 will be compatible with it or not.

How do we ensure whether BOXI set up with 12c is compatible enough?

Currently upon retrieving BO reports,  we are getting "no data with query1"